# Stuck backup process - Backup or restore is already running

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, sql-server, backup

From a few days I'm not able to performe backup. Backup always stuck on the same level - eg backup files have 10GB in jobs I see running backup proces and that it, backup stuck. When I delete that job in  the Check backup and restore job status I see Backup or restore is already running.

I restarted server but nothing is changed.

What can I check/do to solved this issue?

Best regards,

Comment: How are you taking backups? Have you checked the backup logs?

Comment: I make backup by SharePoint and powershell scrip which bun by windows task sheduler. In the backup log on the beging evrything looks correct but in the end there is a timeout and I have just noticed that in a few backup logs file the timeout is on the same database ...

Comment: Let me guess, one of the search database?

Comment: No, this time it's content and I can't backup contnet databases by SQL also.

Comment: And the account you are using to perform backups did work a couple of days ago?

Comment: Everything worked correct and I didn't do any system change, on thursday sql backup performed last time and on friday night SharePoint backup stuck  and so far I'm not able to performe it ... But to be honest I don't see any problem with account and permissions, the backup simple stuck, I have just tried to performe sql backup without database which causes timeout but it looks that the proces it stuck also.

Comment: One thing which I should to add that I can performe backup configuration settings by SharePoint, it works correct but if I trying to backup content it stuck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you Backup on shared folder, if yes then check SQL Server permission there on Shared folder. For me it looks like permission issue.

Yes it will do SharePoint part properly but when it will try to do the backup of SQL Database, that time it will use SQL Server Service account may be that account will not have permission to Shared folder. Another thing you have to Keep in mind SQL Server Service Account should be domain account and Shared Folder Should have read, write permission for that account

Comment: Yes it's Sheard Folder but the backup is running and part of backup is saved corectly on sherd location in backup logs there is a timeout.

Comment: Check my edited answer

Comment: This time it turned out that the problem was in the sql backup proces which stuck. Thanks for support and help.

Comment: If it solved the issue, then kindly mark it as answer